# How to $slice results of foreign collection documents array when mongodb $lookup is used

Tags: mongodb

Here is my code

```
AbcSchema.aggregate([
            { $match: query },
            {
                $lookup: { from: 'xyz', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'place_id', as: 'xyzArray' }
            }
         ])
```

Right now Im getting this result :

```
{
 _id : "abc1",
 abcfield1 : "...",
 abcfield2 : "...",
 xyzArray : [{_id : "xyz1", place_id : "abc1", xyzfield1 : "..."}, 
             {_id : "xyz2", place_id : "abc1", xyzfield1 : "..."},
             {_id : "xyz3", place_id : "abc1", xyzfield1 : "..."},
            ...] //all matching results
}
```

So now lets say I want only 2 documents in xyzArray, then how can I achieve that?

My requirement is to get limit the 'xyzArray' length to 'n' .

Comment: Show us your db structure and expected result.

Comment: @titi23 I have updated my description please look into it.

Comment: Has the below solution resolved your issue?

Comment: @notionquest The below solution works when the 'n' is static. I want dynamic solution, where 'n' might change.

Comment: Has the below solution met your requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the dynamic query. You can change the number inside the **$slice** to get the required number of array elements.

```
db.AbcSchema.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id : "abc1"} },
     {
      $unwind: "$_id"
    },
    {
        $lookup: { from: 'xyz', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'place_id', as: 'xyzArray' }
    },
    { $project: { abcfield1 : 1,
                  abcfield2 : 1,
                  xyzArrayArray: { $slice: ["$xyzArray", 2]  }                     
                }
    }
]).pretty();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using **$project** and **$arrayElemAt**

```
db.AbcSchema.aggregate([
    { $match: {_id : "abc1"} },
     {
      $unwind: "$_id"
    },
    {
        $lookup: { from: 'xyz', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'place_id', as: 'xyzArray' }
    },
    { $project: { abcfield1 : 1,
                  abcfield2 : 1,
                  firstxyzArray: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$xyzArray", 0 ] },
                  secondxyzArray: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$xyzArray", 1 ] }
                }
    }
]).pretty();
```

**Sample Output:-**

```
{
        "_id" : "abc1",
        "abcfield1" : "11",
        "abcfield2" : "22",
        "firstxyzArray" : {
                "_id" : "xyz1",
                "place_id" : "abc1",
                "xyzfield1" : "xyzf1"
        },
        "secondxyzArray" : {
                "_id" : "xyz2",
                "place_id" : "abc1",
                "xyzfield1" : "xyzf1"
        }
}
```